# Criu/crtools restore fails to restore process on a different machine

Tags: save, restore, migrate, process-migration

I am trying to save a process to the disk using [CRIU](http://criu.org/Main_Page), I am able to save and restore it on the same machine, but when I try to restore the saved image on different machine it gives me an error.

I executed the `yes` command found its pid using `ps aux|grep yes`

then to save I did:

```
sudo ./criu dump -t 7483 -D ~/dumped --shell-job
```

then I copied the "dumped" directory to another machine and tried to restore it using following command:

```
sudo ./criu restore -t 7483 -D ../dumped/ --shell-job
```

but got the following error

```
(00.058476) Error (cr-restore.c:956): 7483 killed by signal 7
(00.058526) Error (cr-restore.c:1279): Restoring FAILED.
```

How do I resolve this? I want to migrate a process to a different machine having exactly similar configuration.

**Configuration:**

- Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit desktop
- linux 3.11.0.19-generic
- RAM: 4 GB
- [Output of lscpu](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7351020/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to restore this process on the machine where you dumped it?

Could you run restore with additional keys to get verbose log? Like so:

```
sudo ./criu restore -D ../dumped/ --shell-job -v4 -o restore.log
```

And provide somehow this log?

Btw, -t option at restore is obsoleted. But it doesn't matter in this case, though. =)